# 2 matrices veryfing similarity

Tags: matrices

Show That if matrices A and  B are similar tren there exists other to matrices X and Y so That A=XY and B=YX.no idea.thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ and $B$ similar, then there exists an invertible matrix $S$ such that
$$A=SBS^{-1}$$
and hence, equivalently 
$$B=S^{-1}AS$$

Then choose $X=SB$ and $Y=S^{-1}$

Then clearly

$$A=XY= SBS^{-1}$$
and
$$B=YX=S^{-1}SB$$